# Laravel Eloquent Eager Loading depending on column value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I got a model called `Tag` and that contains a column `tag_type` which values can be one of three: `company`, `office`, or `school`.

For each there is a corresponding model `Company`, `Office` and `School` and in each we have an inverse relation `return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag')` to the `Tag` model which has, in exchange, a `hasOne` relation to each of these three models `return $this->hasOne('App\Company')`

How can I fetch a specific tag with eager loading to these three models that will fetch the tag and specifically ONE of these models depending on the `tag_type`

My attempt at this was:

```
    $tags = Tag::where('ref_id', 123)->get();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $collectionTag = null;
        if($tag->tag_type == 'Company'){
            $collectionTag = $tag->company()->first();
        }
        if($tag->tag_type == 'Office'){
            $collectionTag = $tag->office()->first();
        }
        if($tag->tag_type == 'School'){
            $collectionTag = $tag->school()->first();
        }
        $tag['collectionTag'] = $collectionTag;
    }
    return $tags;
```

Comment: I suggest you to look into this link. [Polymorphic relationships provided by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). Right now, not sure about how your scenario will be mapped but it provides type based linking to models